# Can't find the right command in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Display the total amount on sales and the corresponding commission of Michaels (staff name):

```
select 
    st.lastname Name, count(s.invoiced) "Amount of Sale", st.commission "Commission"
from 
    sales s, staff st
where 
    st.staffno = st.staffno and st.lastname = 'michaels';
```

Can someone tell me if I did it right?

Comment: I think you miss `AS`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Right query will be 
select 
    st.lastname as Name, sum(s.invoiced) as "Amount of Sale", st.commission as "Commission"
from 
    sales s, staff st
where 
    s.staffno = st.staffno and st.lastname = 'michaels';

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to set the title in your table column. Add `AS`

```
select st.lastname AS 'Name', count(s.invoiced) AS 'Amount of Sale', st.commission 
AS 'Commission'
from sales s, staff st
where st.staffno = st.staffno and
st.lastname = 'michaels';
```

Why you have duplicate **WHERE** clauses ?

```
where st.staffno = st.staffno
```

Shouldn't  it be something like `st.staffno = s.idNo` ?

Comment: the is any way we can chat as skype or others?

Comment: send you the email if you can check please